# 2019 Moderator Election Pre-Announcement and Interest Check

Tags: discussion, election

It hasn't been long since this community's [most recent election](https://android.stackexchange.com/election/5), barely more than 2 months ago. However, for personal reasons, moderator elect beeshyams has had to step down from the position. Though their service time was short, we would like to thank them for the work they contributed in this time.

Normally due to the proximity to a prior election, we would look at whether we can pull a runner up from the election to take place. However, as the runner up is the only un-elected candidate who participated in the election, it would be victory by default instead of by voting in that scenario.

After consultation with the current moderator team, it's been deemed necessary that we fill the absence in the team sooner rather than later, so **a new election is being prepared to begin collecting questions on January 28th, 2019**.

Since this is sudden and so soon after the most recent election, we've opted to make an announcement about this plan well in advance. This is not only to help inform people of the upcoming election so that they may prepare their platforms as candidates, but also to help determine the number of slots. The moderators are suggesting we fill in **2 slots** - however, for an election to run we require at least N+1 candidates for an N slot election. More is ideal, but at minimum we must ensure that there is enough candidates for there to actually be a meaningful vote by the community to indicate who they support for the role. Since the prior election had a low turnout, though, we're holding this thread to do a bit of an interest check.

This is not an official nomination thread, but it serves both as a means for users to indicate that they'd be interested in the position, or potentially name other users who they believe may be suitable to the role (assuming that said users agree to run). Based on feedback on this thread, we may adjust the slot count for the election once the question collection phase begins.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Grace – and also thanks to beeshyams for serving with us! Speaking with Bryan Adams, I hope we can "wake up the neighbors" here, and get as many candidates as my left hand has fingers! Before you ask: it's a healthy hand (no mutants, no cripples, and I hope it stays that way). So now: Raise yours! We're not Uncle Sam, but we're looking for you ‎

Comment: If we can't find enough people maybe the existing small pool could be voted [pro tempore](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/07/27/moderator-pro-tempore/) - that would look good on their *resume* for a proper (enough people) election that can be scheduled a few months down the road. So-called *permanent* pro-tems are not being suggested in this comment.

Comment: I would be willing to obtain the rep necessary and run, although that is probably not what you want from a moderator candidate. I think you'd rather want someone already established in the community, right?

Comment: I can be a temporary moderator, if I'm needed.

Comment: For the best of this community, I'm willing to run for the election again to fulfill the minimum candidate requirement.

Comment: Should expressions of interest be answers? In a similar thread on Data Science this was specifically requested.

Comment: Sorry, I am not interested in running as a candidate *this time* because I am an idiot.

Comment: @iBug By itself that's not an obstacle to being a moderator. Do you mean you were suspended within last year?

Comment: This got slipped by, but I wasn't planning to require interest expressed as answers. I wouldn't object to answers being posted but unlike on Data Science's part, this site doesn't have quite as dire a turnout to the elections of late and we're holding the election definitively. So that's why I didn't put in a clause for big posty standing-up.